# CMake find_path not working on MinGW

Tags: cmake, mingw

I have an issue when using `find_path` CMake command on windows and MinGW.
Consider the following code:

```
find_path(FINDPATH_TEST stdio.h)
message(STATUS "FINDPATH_TEST: "${FINDPATH_TEST})
```

It works perfectly on Linux, printing: `FINDPATH_TEST: /usr/include`.
However running this code on windows using "MinGW Makefiles" as CMake generator will output:

```
FINDPATH_TEST: FINDPATH_TEST-NOTFOUND
```

Why `find_path` not works in the same way on MinGW?

Comment: is cmake compiled with mingw?

Answer (score 1):

You could check this thread: http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2007-November/017813.html It explains what are the default search paths for various operating systems. You should see which one is used in your case (mingw).

I also believe that you may need to use the cmake version compiled for mingw in order to get that working on your mingw environment. I am not 100% sure though because I didn't use cmake with mingw.